# simplejson/java - how to handle null arrays/lists

Tags: java, simplejson

The following chunk of java deals with simplejson and string/JSONArray conversion.
I'm running jre 1.6 on centos.

My goal, trying to figure out how to handle null array as input text, and converting to the simplejson JSONArray.

The "s" in the chunk represents samples of valid input into the test app.

```
.
.
.
import org.json.simple.*;

    String s="[0,{\"1\":{\"2\":{\"3\":{\"4\":[5,{\"6\":7}]}}}}]";
    String s="[null]";

    Object objm=JSONValue.parse(s);
    JSONArray array=(JSONArray)objm;
    System.out.println(array.size();

//the above works as expected...
however, if i use a string of

    String s="[]";

i get an error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONArray
```

so, I'm trying to understand how i can use "[]" without having to do a check on the text to convert to a [] array...

any thoughts??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just check for it:.

```
if (!"[]".equals(s)) {
  Object objm=JSONValue.parse(s);
  JSONArray array=(JSONArray)objm;
  System.out.println(array.size();
} else {
  // ..
}
```